# How can I transfer a AMI from one region to another with [non-,]Encrypted snapshots. AMI platform changes from windows to other linux

Tags: copy, transfer, snapshot, encryption, boto3

Following are are two sample codes that I tried

Code1:

```
import boto3
session = boto3.session.Session()
ec2_us_east = session.resource('ec2')
snap = ec2_us_east.Snapshot('snap-<id>')
snap.copy(DryRun=False,SourceRegion='us-east-1',SourceSnapshotId=snap.id,Description="testB3Copy",DestinationRegion="us-west-1")
```

Code2:

```
import boto3
ec2_us_east_client = boto3.client('ec2')
ec2_us_east_client.copy_snapshot(DryRun=False,SourceRegion='us-east-1',SourceSnapshotId=<snap-id>,Description="testB3Copy",DestinationRegion="us-west-1")
```

Both generates same error message as shown below:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-65-464cba179f87> in <module>() 
----> 1 ec2_us_east_client.copy_snapshot(DryRun=True,SourceRegion='us-east-1',SourceSnapshotId=snap.id,Description="testB3Copy",DestinationRegion="us-west-1")

/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/botocore/client.pyc in _api_call(self, **kwargs)
    239                     endpoint_prefix=service_model.endpoint_prefix,
    240                     operation_name=operation_name),
--> 241                 model=operation_model, params=request_dict
    242             )
    243

/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/botocore/hooks.pyc in emit(self, event_name, **kwargs)
    150         for handler in handlers_to_call:
    151             logger.debug('Event %s: calling handler %s', event_name, handler)
--> 152             response = handler(**kwargs)
    153             responses.append((handler, response))
    154         return responses

TypeError: copy_snapshot_encrypted() takes exactly 3 arguments (1 given)
```

I'm not sure what is going wrong here. As per the documentation copy_snapshot takes 5 arguments.

Also not sure about whether it is possible to transfer Encrypted snapshot using boto2+

When you transfer Windows AMI from one region to another (by copying snapshots and registering an AMI manually or via scripts), final AMI's platform property will be set as "Other Linux" instead of "Windows"
NOTE: platform windows to other Linux change can be ignored since when the virtualization_type is hvm, it doesn't matter. VM will bootup normally since Fully virtualized VMs boot by executing mbr.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the moment, Boto (v2+,3+), AWS CLI or Amazon console doesn't support AMI with encrypted volume transfer between regions.

Also Boto (v2+,3+) doesn't transparently support transfer of AMIs with encrypted snapshots

NOTE: There is a hard limit of 5 active snapshot transfer, which probably creates a challenge for AMI Transfer feature (Not sure). But AWSCLI (latest version as of today) supports Encrypted blockdevice transfer.

So here is what I did. I have used AWS CLI to transfer snapshot and Python-boto to manage the transfer

```
1. Shellscript
   INPUT(CommandlineArgs) takes snapshotID, source region and destination region as input
   Output snapshotID or <predeterminedstring, eg: TfrFailed>(incase transfer failed due to 5ActiveSnapshotTransferAcrossRegionLimit) 

2. Python (boto)
   Input(CommandlineArgs) takes AMI_ID(s)
   Logic:
    for each ami 
       collect information about snapshots
     try
       initiates transfer of each snapshot (by calling shell script which uses AWS CLI)
     catch exception (output of shell script == <predeterminedstring>
       retry after sometime (you would be here if you had hit the hard limit of 5 active snapshots
     finally (once all snapshots are transfered)
       register a new ami (optionally transfer all tags from source AMI to target AMI)
       print SRC_AMI_ID "-->" DST_AMI_ID
    done
   Output: <SourceLocation_AMI-ID> --> <TargetLocation_AMI-ID
```

NOTE: you might see that the target AMI looses information about "platform" since when we transfer AMIs this way we are not refering to a manifest file and I couldn't figure out a way to forcefully set platform -> "Windows". But you can ignore that, and it should work just fine if you set "Virtualization_type" as "hvm".

NOTE: If you do this and want to use "Get password feature", you probably are out of luck since this would need platform to be set as "Windows"

Incase of paravirtual, most likely your target AMI won't bootup unless your new ami has sufficient properties configured for PVGRUB

Answer (score 1):

**Update**: Boto 3 release 0.0.7 should now include support for copying encrypted snapshots in the Botocore client interface.

---

Right now there is a customization to help with this method in Botocore, and it is used by the AWS CLI. It is not yet available in Boto 3. Botocore provides two public interfaces, the newer one being the low-level clients exposed in Boto 3. These do not yet support the customization that is set up here:

https://github.com/boto/botocore/blob/develop/botocore/handlers.py#L398

We are working to get this plumbed through so that this and a few other calls just work in Boto 3, like they do in the AWS CLI today. The change will require a Botocore code change and release, and then it should just work in Boto 3.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I actually figured it out. How soon can we expect boto3 rc. I tried using current boto3 package. it looked very different from boto2 and wasn't able to write simple codes... May be I was using an older version or my brain was hooked on to boto2 way of doing things... Can't wait to switch to boto3 and learn that.

Comment: Now that we have got KMS for key management w.r.t snapshots and volumes, I think it would be little more easy to deal with AMI/Snapshot transfer since SIGV4 might not be primarily responsible for encryption of the block device. I'm sure that you are aware of this but just in case...